# pandoc: add html events such as onload when converting from markdown

Tags: javascript, html, markdown, pandoc

When converting from Markdown to HTML, I'd love to add a custom `onload` event handler in the generated html page, like this:

```html
<body onload="myOnLoad();">
```

It this possible with `pandoc`? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

1. use a custom template, see the pandoc [manual section on templates](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#templates), or
2. write a short JavaScript script which uses the [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method instead, and add the script to the document, e.g. via [`-H`](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--include-in-header).

Comment: Thanks. I took #2 because I already have that script with -H. With `window.addEventListener('load', OnLoad);`, I managed to make it work.